# In my Django model, how can I automatically populate a field?

Tags: python, django, model

I have a Django model for a book club, which contains a single president, and many members. Naturally, a club president would automatically be considered a member as well. How can I configure my members field to always add the president, with room for expansion? Here is my current Club model:

```
class Club(models.Model):
    president = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='president')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=320)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='members')
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't configure "members" field automatically.

I would recommend using `ManyToMany` relationship with `through` option, so you will be able to add extra field to relationship between Member(User) and Club. e.g. `is_president=True`. (see docs example [ManyToMany.through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships))

```
# models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class Club(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=320)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(through="Membership", related_name='clubs')

class Member(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOne(get_user_model())

class Membership(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member)
    club = models.ForeignKey(Club)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    is_president = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

However in your current model setup you can overload `Model.save()` which is not recommended, or use Django's build in [post-save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save) which is prefered.

1, Create method (or function) which will check if "president" is "member" of Club

```
# models.py
def check_president_as_member(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    #check if instance.president is in instance.members.all()
    #add president to members if necessary
    return True
```

2, Register method with post-save on Club model.

```
# models.py
from django.db import models 
models.signals.post_save.connect(check_president_as_member, sender=Club, dispatch_uid="check_president_as_member_post_save", weak=False)
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to validate that the `president` is always in `members` and if not, to add the president to members. You can do this by validating model objects. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects).

Answer (score -1):

A better design for your model will be

```
class Club(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=320)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='members')
    member_type = models.IntegerField(default=0) #0 member 1 president
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

What I have done is removed the president column as it was redundant. President will also be the member of club so use a flag `member_type` to identify which member is president.

This will also give you flexibility to change the president by just changing the `member_type` column.

Comment: You use an IntegerField for the field type. So should the integer refer to the ID of the particular user that is the president?

Comment: As I mentioned in the comment ahead of field declaration that `0` for member and `1` for president. That means for president this value will be set to `1`. You can take a Boolean column as well with field name like `is_president`.

Comment: Gotcha. One last question, wouldn't member_type be a field under a Member model, and not Club? Because there needs to be a member type for each member, correct?

Comment: @Elliot, You can choose any name to this column. Idea was to explain the logic to maintain a flag to identify which member is the president of club.

Comment: If you are not happy with the solution then please at-least write a reason in comments after down voting :-)